# How to compare the diff between 2 orgs with sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, diff

really need your help.

I have 2 sandboxes which have their own development, now that i want to merge them into one, i want to make a comparison of diff between those 2 orgs.

I have tried running this command

[image]

 it can only works on a few components like class and lwc that i know of

 but it would throw error if i run it on Object metadata

[image]

I have updated sfdx-cli to the latest version but it is still failing to get diff on Objects metadata and many other kind of metadata.

Answer (score 4):

The UI command only works to diff the local repo to an org. To compare two orgs, retrieve both, then use a tool like diff or WinDiff to check the differences:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -k manifest.xml -u sandbox1 -r sandbox1 -z
sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve -k manifest.xml -u sandbox2 -r sandbox2 -z
```

Where `manifest.xml` is a [Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_package.htm), `-u` is the username or alias for the org to retrieve, `-r` is the destination directory, and `-z` automatically decompresses the ZIP files. Other options are available, e.g. if you have built a Package or Change Set in the UI, you can use `-p` instead of `-k`.

And then compare the differences:

```
diff -r sandbox1 sandbox2
```

Comment: right, thanks for your advice... :thumbsup

Answer (score 1):

You may also try [sforgcompare](https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/) to compare the orgs.